# Symfony FOSUserBundle overriding forms

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override FOSUserBundle default registration form. To be exact I'm trying to remove username. The problem is probably in services.yml maybe. but not sure.
services.yml file:

```
services:
    user.registration.form.type:
        class: Atotrukis\MainBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_registration }
```

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

RegistrationFormType.php

```
<?php

namespace Atotrukis\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->remove('username');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: [This thread may give you some more help](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/555). Are you using version 1.3 or 2+? [Here's also a condensed doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md), even though it may not give you exactly what you want

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.5.3 and FOSUSerBundle 2.0

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code.

Inheritance of forms isn't done with class extends, but with definition of `getParent()` method. You define name of service. E.g.

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }
}
```

You forgot define class in bundle configuration

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            type: user.registration.form.type
```